# Ubuntu frozen monitor after closing a game

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, freeze

my english is not that good i'm slowly learning and hopefully i can type what i need to explain.
so i used to use linux a lot, and i have a good exp that a linux user needs. i used a lot of distros based on ubuntu and archlinux distros as well.
and now i came back to my lovely distro (vanilla Ubuntu 22.04.3) and this issue is an old one, but still confuses me
so when i use to play a game, or use any heavy program let's say i wanna open minecraft, so after playing a while and close the game the monitor that minecraft was in got frozen in the frame it was and i cannot use everything like the dock, buttons, files.. etc moved to the another monitor as it is a fallback thing idk
how can i avoid this issue and fix it probably? i used nvidia 535 latest one and i'm pretty my nvidia card and my pc are good to handle a game like minecraft i play valorant a lot (on windows)
and nothing happened, so how can i fix this and what should i provide to you guys to help, thank you.

i asked in discord community before and that's what they asked me to provide..

output of `sudo inxi -F` https://pastebin.com/xEwJmkTr

output of `sudo dmesg` https://pastebin.com/r7x89MH1

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/2016924 does this help?

Comment: still the same issue, nothing fixed